# Modify youtube video size on one page and show another size on different page

Tags: excerpt, embed, youtube, oembed

I have to display three videos (custom post type) on my first page. When clicking on the link, the post is displayed and video should be in default width.

Can you help to find out how to change width of videos (like youtube)?

This is how I display info now, and this displays all content (including video). I need somehow to show just `the_excerpt` + small video.

```
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <?php the_title(
            '<h2 class="entry-title">
                <a href="' . get_permalink() . '"
                title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '"
                rel="bookmark">',
            '</a></h2>' );
        ?>          
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: How is the URL or embed code of the video stored? In a custom field or in the post content?

Comment: Provide demo link.

Comment: @renathy, please provide answers to the questions in these comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using WordPress' [Embeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds)
 feature. Generally speaking [`wp_embed_defaults()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_defaults) gives you the information you need. A look at the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L2031) discloses the possibilities you have:

```
2017    /**
2018     * Create default array of embed parameters.
2019     *
2020     * The width defaults to the content width as specified by the theme. If the
2021     * theme does not specify a content width, then 500px is used.
2022     *
2023     * The default height is 1.5 times the width, or 1000px, whichever is smaller.
2024     *
2025     * The 'embed_defaults' filter can be used to adjust either of these values.
2026     *
2027     * @since 2.9.0
2028     *
2029     * @return array Default embed parameters.
2030     */
2031    function wp_embed_defaults() {
2032            if ( ! empty( $GLOBALS['content_width'] ) )
2033                    $width = (int) $GLOBALS['content_width'];
2034    
2035            if ( empty( $width ) )
2036                    $width = 500;
2037    
2038            $height = min( ceil( $width * 1.5 ), 1000 );
2039    
2040            /**
2041             * Filter the default array of embed dimensions.
2042             *
2043             * @since 2.9.0
2044             *
2045             * @param int $width  Width of the embed in pixels.
2046             * @param int $height Height of the embed in pixels.
2047             */
2048            return apply_filters( 'embed_defaults', compact( 'width', 'height' ) );
2049    }
```

As you can see the `global` variable `$content_width` - `$GLOBALS['content_width']` - is the first approach to determine the default width, if it isn't empty it will be used. The theme feature [Content Width](http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width) can be used by adding the following to your `functions.php`:

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 1200;
}
```

Which sets up the width you need. If you don't do that the width defaults to 500px, as you can see above. The height defaults either to 1.5 times the width or - if that is less - to 1000px.

The specified width is a maximum, so your [embed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) won't be wider then that, but will scale down in size. You can possibly support this behavior via CSS, with the following parameters:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Which is generally a recommendation, but not necessarily needed.

The above should normally be enough to scale your embedded contents to the size of the container they are in.

However the look into the source shows another way of modifying the width (and height) value. Which would be by [hooking](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) into the `embed_defaults` filter. More general information about this functionality can be found via the WordPress codex page [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API), which is a good start to learn more about the topic. A specific example on how to apply this possibility to the `embed_defaults` filter looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'embed_defaults', 'wpse150029_change_embed_defaults' );
function wpse150029_change_embed_defaults() {
    return array(
        'width'  => 1200, 
        'height' => 800
    );
}
```

The code would be part of your `functions.php` or a plugin. Theoretically you can use [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to differentiate the values, but it is unlikely needed.

This should cover the possibilities of setting up the width of your embedded content. The rest depends on your [templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) and the CSS of the theme you are using.

As your goal is to show [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) and the video on your home, front- or overview page you have to create your own function to extract the video URL from the post content and use [`wp_oembed_get()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get) to fetch the embed HTML. For example like this:

```
function wpse150029_fetch_youtube_return_embed_html( $content ) {
    // Regex example+explanation can be found here: http://regex101.com/r/vZ6bX6/3
    // note: the first youtube link will be extracted
    $pattern  = '/(?<=(?:\[embed\])|(?:\[embed\]\s)|(?:))';
    $pattern .= '(https?:\/\/)';
    $pattern .= '(:?www\.)?';
    $pattern .= '(:?youtube\.com\/watch|youtu\.be\/)';
    $pattern .= '([\w\?\=\&(amp;)]+)';
    $pattern .= '(?=(?:\[\/embed\])|(?:\s\[\/embed\])|(?:))';
    $pattern .= '/ims';
    preg_match( $pattern, $content, $matches );
    $url = $matches[0];
    $embed_code = wp_oembed_get( $url );
    return $embed_code;
}
```

The above code goes into your `functions.php`. Exemplary usage in your template like shown below:

```
$video_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $video_loop->have_post() ) :
    while ( $video_loop->have_posts() ) : $video_loop->the_post();
        the_title();         
        the_excerpt();
        echo wpse150029_fetch_youtube_return_embed_html( $post->post_content );
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
endif;
```

For a detailed description on that take a look at the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) documentation.

If you are actually want to have thumbnails for your embedded videos, you should take a look at those Q&A's on here:

- [Featured Image of Video from oembed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70752/22534)
- [Setting a post's featured image from an embedded YouTube video](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/25808/22534)

Comment: +1 for such an informative and complete answer.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks, trying to do my best as always :)

Comment: Regexp $pattern has some error, I have found another pattern. And $post->content is not defined, what should be instead there?

Comment: As said, should be `$post->post_content`. I did an additional rework on the regex, its more flexible now. Also a quick test on the setup, as far as I can tell it works fine for me. @renathy

Comment: It should be $video_loop->post instead of $post.

Comment: I don't know how you set it up, but normally `$post` is a available in the wordpress loop. @renathy

Comment: And another thing is that unfourtunately $embed_code = wp_oembed_get( $url ); is very very slow and even never ends or something (tested on local computer). This occures with any video link.

Comment: Fetching remote content is always a bottleneck, you should - or at least I would do that - implement a caching mechanism via transients. Personally I probably would do that for the regex too, because its kind of expensive too. Of course you have to implement a functionality to reset/delete the saved/cached data in case of changes. The idea here should be clear, search the site for more information, if you need it, because this has been asked and answered several times. If thats not enough ask a new question. Good luck! @renathy

Comment: embed_defaults filter will not work on Youtube embeds regardless of whether they include width and height inline or not

Comment: Yea, there might be the necessity, especially if it is iframed, to add some extra CSS. Somewhat like the one Hendrik Luehrsen suggested in his answer, but there various variations of that out there. At least I'm thinking that is what you mean. @BradDalton

Answer (score 3):

I think that a better option will be re-size the video with CSS, supposing you have the container `.video_index` for the index of videos and `.video_single` for a single video entry, here is an example.

`.video_index iframe{
  width: 250px;
  height: 170px;
}
.video_single iframe{
  width: 500px;
  height: 360px;
}`

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the old story with (O)embeds and content width. As soon as there is repsonsiveness, the whole system falls apart. A solution, that might be of use is what we do in our themes:

```
/**
 * Change the embed code, so we can apply awesome css shit
 * Called by filter "oembed_result"
 *
 * @author Hendrik Luehrsen
 * @since 1.0
 *
 * @param $html string The oembed html to edit
 *
 * @return string The edited html
 */
function change_oembed($html, $url, $args){
    $video_pattern = "#(\W|^)(youtube|vimeo)(\W|$)#";

    if(preg_match($video_pattern, $url)){
        $new_html = '<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="oembed-wrapper"><img src="'.WP_THEME_URL.'/img/16x9_placeholder.png" />'.$html.'</div>';
    } else {
        $new_html = $html;
    }

    return $new_html;
}
add_filter( 'oembed_result', array($this, 'change_oembed'), 999, 3 );
```

A bit of explanation: The constant WP_THEME_URL is what it claims to be, the URL to the theme. 16x9 placeholder.png is a 16 by 9 pixel transparent PNG. The rest is done in CSS/LESS.

```
.oembed-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 0;

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }

    iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

So what this does, it always scales the embedded video to 100% of the container by keeping the 16x9 aspect ratio. That way you can drop the oembed where ever you want.

I know there are methods out there to drop the image (with pseudo-selectors on .oembed-wrapper) to retain aspect ratio, but I've never read into those. This works in 99% of the cases.