# How to get some information from the_content

Tags: images, content

Hello in index loop 3 lastest post and i want to take only a bit o text and first photo or youtube - and here is the problem, because i can use the_excerpt or i can use get_post_meta to take text, to take picture i can use the_post_thumbnail but i have no idea how i can get youtube as player with the movie, it's always going as text...

```
 <div class="article-image">
<div class="opis-article">
<?php echo the_excerpt(); ?>
<div class="art-en"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tytul-en', true); ?></a></h2><p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'en', true); ?></p><span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">read more</a></span></div>
<div class="art-pl"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tytul-pl', true); ?></a></h2><p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pl', true); ?></p><span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">czytaj więcej</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

any idea ?

Comment: Can you provide simplified example of what post content would be and what you would like to retrieve from it? I guess you are talking about oembed here, but it is a little hard to follow your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize the [video shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode) - `[video]` - with the function [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode). Exemplary usage would be like this:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[video src="your-source-file.mp4"]' );
```

Extra information:
I have given an extensive [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/151557/22534) to a similar question a couple of weeks ago. You should take a look I'm certain it will help you out. Especially if you still need to grab the source from the content. Additionally it offers another possibility to display the video.